# Performance problem with INDEX function and names introduced inside LET/LAMBDA

Tags: excel, performance, lambda, let, excel-lambda

Excel's `INDEX` function shows strange behaviour when the object being indexed is a name introduced in a `LET` construct or a parameter of a `LAMBDA`. The behaviour is consistent on Windows and Mac.

Suppose cell `B2` contains the formula

```
=SEQUENCE(50000)
```

Then the following formulas are all relatively performant:

```
=MAP(SEQUENCE(2000),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(B2#,x)))

=LAMBDA(MAP(SEQUENCE(2000),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(B2#,x))))()

=LET(mgen,LAMBDA(B2#),LAMBDA(MAP(SEQUENCE(2000),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(mgen(),x)))))()
```

The following formulas, however, are terribly slow

```
=LET(m,B2#,MAP(SEQUENCE(2000),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(m,x))))

=LET(m,B2#,LAMBDA(MAP(SEQUENCE(2000),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(m,x)))))()

=LAMBDA(m,MAP(SEQUENCE(2000),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(m,x))))(B2#)
```

The performance problem gets the worse the longer array `B2` is. You can crash Excel with the latter 3 formulas when you replace 50000 by 500000 in `B2`, while the first three formulas still work perfectly fine.

Note that the length of `B2` (the array indexed) should in theory not have any impact on performance, since `INDEX` is called the exact same number of times in all my examples.

To me, `INDEX` seems to have performance problems whenever the first argument does not directly refer to a worksheet range.

Yet if that is so -- how can I efficiently (in constant time) get the n-th element of a LET/LAMBDA-named array?

I cannot work around this by writing the indexed array into a cell, since in my case, the indexed array is the result of another lambda.

Edit for clarification: The only purpose of the `MAP`/`SEQUENCE(2000)` construct in my examples is to make 2000 separate calls to `INDEX`, in order for the performance differences to become visible. The construct is completely unrelated to the problem. The performance problems occur whenever I make a lot of `INDEX` calls with the first argument being a LET/LAMDA name.

Second edit: It seems, however, that some kind of loopy construct is needed to reproduce the problem. I have not been able to reproduce the problem with 2000 separate `LET`/`INDEX` formulas in 2000 cells.

Comment: I also posted this here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/da2f677a-3735-ed11-a81b-000d3a7dd504

Comment: Why not just do `=LET(m,B2#,INDEX(m,sequence(2000))`   or just `=TAKE(B2#,2000)`

Comment: I just tried to create a minimal example demonstrating the problem. The indices I actually need are not sequential. I do need to INDEX single elements because the index I need to access next depends on the value just read.

Comment: A combination of DROP and TAKE seems to be slow as well :-(

Comment: Then, this question boils down to, "Why did Microsoft not make their function more performant?" Which is a question we have been asking since they introduced the heavy calc formulas like SUMIFS and COUNTIFS.  And the answer...No one know but Microsoft.   Maybe I would suggest taking your real life formula and need to codereview to see if anyone can help make it more performant.

Comment: Re "*To me, INDEX seems to have performance problems whenever the first argument does not directly refer to a worksheet range.*", Scott's suggestion of `=LET(m,B2#,INDEX(m,SEQUENCE(2000)))` would appear to contradict this statement, since it is as performant as your first three examples.

Comment: No, that is not a contradiction. I suspect that a call to `INDEX` is slow when the array being indexed into is a LET name, irrespective of how many values you request from the array in that one call. In the example you mention, `INDEX` is called only once. I suspect this call is indeed much slower (measured in microseconds) than `INDEX(B2#,SEQUENCE(2000))` would be, yet since it is only a single call, we do not notice the difference and do not care. If you have a thousand such calls, you do see the difference, though.

Comment: It *is* a contradiction to your statement "*"To me, INDEX seems to have performance problems **whenever the first argument does not directly refer to a worksheet range**.*". Re your latest comment, am I to understand that you believe the `LET` function is forcing the `INDEX` construction to be called more than once?

Comment: No, I did not mean that the LET function forces the INDEX function to be called more often. I say that *if* we have a lot of calls to INDEX (for whatever reason), we run into performance problems when we use LET even when there would not be any performance issues without LET.